# How can I call a form and run its progress bar from the main form?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I´m struggling with this piece of code where I want to call a very small form with just a progress bar on marquee style to show the user that we´re awaiting for the process I start on `Dim procMethod2 As Process = Process.Start(psiMethod2)` block to finish.

The form is being called, shown and terminated as expected, however, the progress bar on it does not move while the process is being ran in the background...

I´ve read several articles about this but all were small Subs being used for this... The code below is a big function and I want to manage this inside it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
                Try
                    Dim psiMethod2 As New ProcessStartInfo
                    psiMethod2.UseShellExecute = False
                    psiMethod2.WorkingDirectory = Path
                    psiMethod2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    psiMethod2.FileName = strWTReportingFullPath 'Full path of WT-Reporting.exe
                    psiMethod2.Arguments = ExecutableArgs 'Arguments to be passed to WT-Reporting.exe

                    'Launch the process in a hidden window
                    Dim procMethod2 As Process = Process.Start(psiMethod2)

                    'Call the form containing the progress bar
                    frmProgressBarWTReporting.Show(Me)

                    'Set up progress bar settings
                    frmProgressBarWTReporting.pbWTReporting.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5
                    frmProgressBarWTReporting.pbWTReporting.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee

                    'Awaits the process to terminate
                    procMethod2.WaitForExit()

                    'Close the form once the process is terminated
                    frmProgressBarWTReporting.Close()

                    If chkboxAddToNCBase.Checked = False Then
                        bolToolListsWereMigrated = False
                        Try
                            StartExplorer(Path)
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Error when opening the export folder in Windows Explorer!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                        End Try
                    Else
                        AddAssociateFileIntoNCBase(intProgramIDAsInteger, strToolListFullPath)
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: I just realized - you are starting up an external process, but you seem to be expecting your internal code base to follow the progress of the external application - things don't work that way. This would only work if the external process is reporting its progress AND your application is capturing that information, and changing the value of the progress bar through code.

Comment: Not really, I don´t want to have the progress of my external process because that varies and cannot be measured... We can´t know in advance how long it will take... so my goal is just to show a form with a progress bar set to marquee style so it always starts over as long the form is running... once the external process is exited I close the form...

Comment: When I call this form alone through a button or set it as the startup form it works fine.. the problem is when a process.start is fired than the form progress bar simply hangs...

Comment: I tried to learn about a background worker as well but it´s not working either... I doing something very wrong...

Comment: While not the ideal way, `Application.DoEvents()` can allow you to verify that your progressbar value is changing correctly - then once you learn more asynchronous methods, you can apply those.

Comment: I assume you are using a timer or loop to change the progressbar value? Could you post the code of that `frmProgressBarWTReporting`

Comment: Private Sub frmProgressBarWTReporting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbWTReporting.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5
        pbWTReporting.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    End Sub

Comment: How am I suppose to format code in comments? Sorry for the bad layout...

Comment: @vbnet3d - Calling `Application.DoEvents()` is less than "not ideal", it's bad bad bad.

Comment: @Enigmativity That is not quite true. It is not the best option, but it has occasional good reasons for use, including debugging a UI update issue - see http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/

Comment: @vbnet3d - That article doesn't seem to say there are "occasional good reasons for use". It seems to say that there are occasions where it is better than other bad choices. It does say that "DoEvents messes up the normal flow of your application" and that's where it is bad for 99% of programmers who don't understand how much of an impact it can be. It is bad bad bad - which is sometimes better than terrible terrible terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it in a very simple way that worked for me - **A Do While Loop**.

The code of the form I call is as simple as this:

```
  Private Sub frmProgressBarWTReporting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbWTReporting.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5
        pbWTReporting.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
  End Sub
```

And this is the sub code:

```
                '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                '// Method 1, launch a process at run time passing arguments //
                '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Try
                    Dim psiMethod2 As New ProcessStartInfo
                    psiMethod2.UseShellExecute = False
                    psiMethod2.WorkingDirectory = Path
                    psiMethod2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    psiMethod2.FileName = strWTReportingFullPath 'Full path of WT-Reporting.exe
                    psiMethod2.Arguments = ExecutableArgs 'Arguments to be passed to WT-Reporting.exe

                    frmProgressBarWTReporting.Show()
                    Dim procMethod2 As Process = Process.Start(psiMethod2)

                    Do While 1 = 1
                        If procMethod2.HasExited = False Then
                            Application.DoEvents()
                        Else
                            frmProgressBarWTReporting.Close()
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop

                    If chkboxAddToNCBase.Checked = False Then
                        bolToolListsWereMigrated = False
                        Try
                            StartExplorer(Path)
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Erro ao abrir a pasta de exportação no Windows Explorer!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erro ao abrir a pasta de exportação!")
                        End Try
                    Else
                        AddAssociateFileIntoNCBase(intProgramIDAsInteger, strToolListFullPath)
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
```

Thank you everyone for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're blocking the UI thread with the call to `procMethod2.WaitForExit()`. Since the UI is blocked it cannot update the progress bar.

There is an overload for `WaitForExit` that takes an `Integer` that you can use though. The `Integer` specifies the number of milliseconds to wait for the process to exit. If the time runs out the call returns `False`, but if the process exits (or has already exited) then it returns `True`. You can use a `Timer` to call `WaitForExit` periodically and then only respond when the method returns `True`. That way you are not blocking the UI thread and the updates can occur.

Here's what you need to try:

```
    Dim psiMethod2 As New ProcessStartInfo
    psiMethod2.UseShellExecute = False
    psiMethod2.WorkingDirectory = Path
    psiMethod2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psiMethod2.FileName = strWTReportingFullPath 'Full path of WT-Reporting.exe
    psiMethod2.Arguments = ExecutableArgs 'Arguments to be passed to WT-Reporting.exe

    'Launch the process in a hidden window
    Dim procMethod2 As Process = Process.Start(psiMethod2)

    Dim timer As New Timer()
    timer.Interval = 100

    Dim handler As EventHandler = Nothing
    handler =
        Sub(o, e)
            If procMethod2.WaitForExit(1) Then

                timer.Stop()
                RemoveHandler timer.Tick, handler
                timer.Dispose()

                frmProgressBarWTReporting.Close()

                If chkboxAddToNCBase.Checked = False Then
                    bolToolListsWereMigrated = False
                    Try
                        StartExplorer(Path)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("Error when opening the export folder in Windows Explorer!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
                    End Try
                Else
                    AddAssociateFileIntoNCBase(intProgramIDAsInteger, strToolListFullPath)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub

    AddHandler timer.Tick, handler

    timer.Start()
```

And, just a small side-note, you need to stop doing catches like `Catch ex As Exception` as they hide errors and make your code more buggy.

Comment: Unfortunately that 'e' in ` Sub(o, e)` in the code did not work as this Sub also uses e as the event argument.... I ended up giving up of showing that bar...

Comment: @DanielSantos - So change the `e` in my code to `e2`. No big deal.